# Flask: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_active'

Tags: python, flask

I'm using PostgreSQL as my database. It's my first-day using flask, but after many attempts to create a working login system I started to get many errors, but now only one left. I don't really know the reason, I tried researching, but I still don't understand where I'm making a mistake. I easily check if the user exists with the - `user_management check_login` function

```
class user_management:

    def __init__(self):
        pass


    def check_login(self, username, password):
        try:

            self.username = username
            self.password = password

            # psycopg2 stuff
            self.connection = psycopg2.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=5432, password='ssss412', database='postgres', user='postgres')
            self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
            self.query = f"select * from users where username=('{self.username}') and password=('{self.password}')"
            self.cursor.execute(self.query)
            self.connection.commit()
            self.result = self.cursor.fetchone()

        except KeyError:
            pass

        except Exception as error:
            print('error', error)

        finally:
            self.result = self.result or None

            if self.result:
                return True
            elif not self.result:
                return False
            else:
                return False


User = user_management()

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    print('idddd', user_id)
    return 2

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('username', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=15)])
    password = PasswordField('password', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=8, max=80)])
    remember = BooleanField('remember me')

class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('email', validators=[InputRequired(), Email(message='Invalid email address'), Length(max=50)])
    username = StringField('username', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=15)])
    password = PasswordField('password', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=8, max=80)])

@app.route('/') # Home
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print(form.username.data, form.password.data)
        login_check = User.check_login(form.username.data, form.password.data)
        if login_check is True: # Logged in
            verification_check = User.check_verification(form.username.data, form.password.data)
            if verification_check is False:
                logout_user()
                return render_template('verification.html')
            elif verification_check is True:
                print('Verified')
                login_user(form.username.data, remember=form.remember.data)
                return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
            elif verification_check == 'noacc':
                return render_template('index.html')
            elif verification_check == 'error':
                return render_template('index.html')
            return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

        elif login_check is False: # Wrong cred
            return render_template('index.html')

    return render_template('login.html',form=form)
```

Edit: posting the whole error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\interkodas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\interkodas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\interkodas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\interkodas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\interkodas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\interkodas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\interkodas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\interkodas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\interkodas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\interkodas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\interkodas\Desktop\login -ex\app.py", line 170, in login
    login_user(form.username.data, remember=form.remember.data)
  File "C:\Users\interkodas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 158, in login_user
    if not force and not user.is_active:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_active'
```

Comment: `except Exception` is bad practice, be careful. Please share the **entire** error message.

Comment: I think something is wrong on this side - `@login_manager.user_loader`, I was watching tutorial how to do it, but it was on sqllite, so there are some difference

Comment: You need to use the `User` object to log in not the string from the form. Don't use this `login_user(form.username.data)` instead use `login_user(user)`

Answer (score 2):

The Flask-Login [login_user(user, remember, duration, force, fresh)](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_login.login_user) method takes a user object as the first parameter, not a string representing the user.

One common way to get a user object is as follows (where `User` is the user model in your application, derived from `db.Model`):

```
user = User.query.get(form.username.data)
```

Some additional help can be found [here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins).

Comment: But I'm using PostgreSQL, I have no db models.

Comment: Undefined variable 'db'

Comment: When you use Flask to build a web site and you want your users to have to authenticate to gain access, then you need users configured somewhere. You're using PostreSQL to store your data so you should have, or should create, a users table. And then you should have a model that represents those users so you can easily access them in the DB. This is basic Flask/Flask-Login auth, so you should read a tutorial on this before going much further.

Comment: I have my Postgresql table with my users, but I dont know how to create a db model which fits the case I'm stuck on

Comment: That's where a Flask/Flask-Login tutorial will help you. Here are a couple: https://hackersandslackers.com/flask-login-user-authentication/ or https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database